# How to specify fixed option in arima for ar1 and ar24 observations

Tags: r

I want to run a time series forecast on a hourly series. I just need to include the AR1 and AR24 observation as per my ACF & PACF. Can someone guide me how to specify this option in R? Below is my code.

```
w_fcast3_mod <- arima(w_fcast3, 
order=c(24,0,0),fixed=c(NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NA,
transform.pars = FALSE)
```

I don't get an error however, when I try to check the summary I get the following only. It's not showing the standard errors and the coefficients.

> summary(w_fcast3)
>       Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.     NA's 
>   -8688.00  -385.00     0.00     0.19   391.00  9486.00       24

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved, its working fine I am able to get the desired output now. Not sure what was wrong. Though MAPE is coming as INF need to investigate it.
Call:
arima(x = w_fcast3, order = c(24, 0, 0), transform.pars = FALSE, fixed = c(NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA))

Coefficients:
         ar1  ar2  ar3  ar4  ar5  ar6  ar7  ar8  ar9  ar10  ar11  ar12  ar13  ar14  ar15  ar16  ar17  ar18  ar19
      0.4257    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
s.e.  0.0072    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      ar20  ar21  ar22  ar23     ar24  intercept
         0     0     0     0  -0.4938     0.1531
s.e.     0     0     0     0   0.0072     4.8476

sigma^2 estimated as 252262:  log likelihood = -72047.16,  aic = 144102.3

Training set error measures:
                      ME     RMSE      MAE MPE MAPE      MASE     ACF1
Training set -0.04815756 502.2573 359.4868 NaN  Inf 0.7315617 0.197388